# Filtering Array but keeping the indexPath position

Tags: arrays, swift, uisearchbar

I am using a `UISearchController` in my `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`

I am filtering an array of usernames with a `NSPredicate`:

```
        self.filteredChats.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (self.gruppenNamen as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredChats = array as! [String]
```

Is there a way to store the indexPath of each filtered element?
I need to know that in order to display my cells correctly, since I am also using arrays for images and other data.

Comment: It'd be maybe more interesting to not have various array, one for the names, one for the image, but only one array with custom objects init (which would hold a name, an image, etc.). It would avoid you to synchronize theses various array.

Comment: Use array of dictionary. So each dictionary will contain information of each user so at time of filtering array you get dictionary with images and names in same order as you want.

Comment: Create model of user and use that.

Comment: Yes i figured this, but there was a lot old code needed to be reviewed. Since it was working I just needed a simple workaround. Anyways I will do it just once again with custom Object arrays. Thanks

Comment: You could use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`, on `gruppenNamen`, that would returns the indexes of objects (let's name it `let targetIndexes`) that pass a test manually written that would mimic your predicate. Then you could use `objectsAtIndexes:`: `let arrayNamen = (self.gruppenNamen as NSArray).objectsAtIndexes(targetIndexes)`, and `letArrayImagen = (self.yourArrayOfImages as NSArray).objectsAtIndexes(targetIndexes)`.

Comment: @Larme great solution! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's says that you have `gruppenNamen` and `gruppenImages`. You want to keep them synchronized.
I would strongly suggest that you create a custom class with a property name, and a property image.

Since you seem to not want that, you could use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` and `objectsAtIndexes:`. I don't use Swift, so I'll code in Objective-C, but it should be easily translated.

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [self.gruppenNamen indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        return [(NSString *)obj rangeOfString:searchController.searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound;
}];
self.filteredChat = [self. gruppenNamen objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
self.filteredImages = [self.gruppenImages objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

I used `rangeOfString:options` for the equivalent of `contains[c]` of your predicate. You could use a `NSPredicate` here too.